# Router connection on usb to ethernet adapter

Tags: usb, router, ethernet, adapter

I have a router that is connected via USB, as the USB drivers are the only ones I can find online. I was going to setup a little network with a switch and probably a WAP as well. The only problem is my router won't work on ethernet.

If I plugged in my router to the switch with a usb to ethernet adapter would that work? Or would it still require the ethernet drivers?

I am using Win7 x64, and the router is a BT Home Hub, I'm not sure of the model no.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you update the post and specify which router is used? And which OS?

As to the answer: **No, an USB to ethernet adapter would not solve things**

If you can not get `ethernet <-> router` working then `USB to ethernet <-> ethernet <-> router` is not going to work either.

And no drivers other than those for your network card are needed to use ethernet.

Comment: Updated post. The network drivers bit makes sense now, I don't know why I didn't think of that. +1

Comment: What do you get if you plug a ethernet cable into a computer (set to DHCP) and into one of the four ethernet sockets on the home hub. Does the computer get an IP via DHCP. If it does try typing the IP of the default gateway in a webbrowser.

Comment: The router is on DHCP, I will try connecting to the router's web interface when I get home tonight, thanks.